# How to change IObservable Func predicates at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive, dynamic-data, rx.net

I'm new to dynamic data and in general the reactive extension world and I'm currently facing a following problem, where I'd like to change the `IObservable<Func<T,bool>>` predicates at runtime by using the dynamic data package and thus the reactive extensions in .NET (C#).

Considering the following situation, I have a **DataGrid** with some columns of type **integer**, lets say **A,B,C**. Furthermore, there is a filter UI where the user can add multiple filters, like **A == 6** or a combination of filter expressions, like **A == 7 || A == 3 || B == 5**, etc. So basically my method returning a `Func<T, bool>` delegate looks like this:

```
private Func<T, bool> FilterOnA(string id)
{
    return n => n.Id == int.Parse(id);
}
```

And the Filter method call in the data pipeline:

```
    // sourceList is used to fill the ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> while receiving data from an event pattern

    sourceList.Connect()                        // SourceList<T>
              .Filter(filterViewModel.FilterOnA)
              .Bind(out _itemsBinding)          // private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
              .DisposeMany()
              .Subscribe();
```

As I mentioned above, the user shall be able to add/remove/modify and more importanlty combine the filter expressions all together.

Since the dynamic's data Filter method is taking a `Func<T,bool>` or an `IObservable<Func<T,bool>>`, one possible solution might look like this:

```
public IObservable<Func<T,bool>> Filter1 {get;} 
public IObservable<Func<T,bool>> Filter2 {get;}
public IObservable<Func<T,bool>> Filter3 {get;}
public IObservable<Func<T,bool>> FilterX {get;}

public IObservable<Func<T,bool>> AllFiltersCombined => Filter1.CombineLatest(Filter2,Filter3,FilterX, (f1,f2,f3,fx) => AggregatePredicatesAnd(f1,f2,f3,fx));


public static Func<T,Bool> AggregatePredicatesAnd(params Func<T,bool>[] predicates) 
{
    return predicates.Aggregate<Func<T,bool>>((fa,fb) => (T t) => fa(t) && fb(t));
}
```

Now, my problem is, how to write this in a more generic way? How to combine for e.g. `0 to n` Filters? And what is about different filter types, e.g. a combination of **A <= 7 && A != 5**?

Comment: What about storing Filter1..X in an collection, instead of explicit properties? Or at least map those properties to an underlying collection?

Comment: Actually, they are in ObservableCollection :) However, I might consider having a separation of Filters for e.g. different columns. Even, if the are in a collection, I don't know how to build/combine different operators in this aggregate function.

Comment: Off top of the head, something like this pops up:   bool And<T>(T arg) => predicates.All( predicate => predicate(arg) );

Comment: Why is each filter an `IObservable<Func<T,bool>>` instead of a `Func<T,bool>`

Comment: You can't just update the Func<T,bool> predicate... The new expression won't be assigned. See docs: https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData the filtering section.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the ApplyFilters operation shown here:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> Apply<T>(this List<T> list, Action<List<T>> action)
    {
        action(list);

        return list;
    }

    public static IObservable<T> ApplyFilters<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<Func<T, bool>> AddFilter, IObservable<Func<T, bool>> RemoveFilter)
    {
        // Project AddFilter to a func that adds a filter to a list of filters
        var adding = AddFilter.Select(func => (Action<List<Func<T, bool>>>)(list => list.Add(func)));

        // Project RemoveFilter to a func that removes a filter from a list of filters
        var removing = RemoveFilter.Select(func => (Action<List<Func<T, bool>>>)(list => list.Remove(func)));

        // Return an observable that...
        return Observable
            // ... merges the add and remove operations ...
            .Merge(adding, removing)
            // ... and applies them to an initially empty list ...
            .Scan(new List<Func<T, bool>>(), (list, change) => list.Apply(change))
            // ... and project every list change to a new observable
            // by applying all operations to the source observable ...
            .Select(list => list.Aggregate(source, (s, f) => s.Where(f)))
            // ... and finally subscribing to the new observable
            .Switch();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public IObservable<Item> _source;

    public IObservable<Func<Item, bool>> _addFilter;

    public IObservable<Func<Item, bool>> _removeFilter;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        FilteredItems = _source.ApplyFilters(_addFilter, _removeFilter);
    }

    public IObservable<Item> FilteredItems { get; }
}

public class Item  {  }
```

Limitations:

1. No consideration has been made regarding `Func<T, bool>` equivalence. You may need to strongly type each filter func to ensure it's able to be added / removed from the internal list of filters correctly.
2. No consideration has been made regarding grouping && and || operations (i.e. `(A == 7 && B == "Hello") || C == -1)`). If this is important you will definitely need to strongly type the filters (per 1) and add a group identifer. You could then use a `GroupBy` on the List prior to performing an `Aggregate` on the observable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll mark this as useful.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to ibeebs answer, I've also discovered another possible solution. In order to build possible combinations of filters, one might use the Dynamic Expressions lib: https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions
and create expressions like this one:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> e2 = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<T, bool>("Id == 7 or Id == 9");
```

or more complex ones.

Since I've mentioned in my question that the User is able to create the filters via UI, it is not a big deal then to build string expressions like `"Id == 7 or Id == 9"`.

Such `Expression` can be simply compiled to a `Func<T, bool>`.